# jqueryui draggable question: how to drag multiple elements at the same time?

Tags: jquery-ui, draggable

Let's say I have something set to be dragged:

```
<div class="container">
  <div id="draggable-1"></div>
  <div id="draggable-3"></div>
  <div id="draggable-4"></div>
  <div id="draggable-5"></div>
</div>
```

Is it possible to set jqueryui's draggable api so I can drag multiple draggable elements at the same time? 
Thanks.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/793559/grouping-draggable-objects-with-jquery-ui-draggable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is a guess but try

set no style sheet on container so it is set as a group. then do this

```
$(function() {

$(".container").draggable();

});
```

then when you drag the entire container drags as a group including all elements inside.

here is a working example of what i did.

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">

#draggable-1,#draggable-2,#draggable-3,#draggable-4,#draggable-5 {

width:100px;
height:100px;
background:red;
margin-bottom:10px;

}

.container {
}
</style>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://jqueryui.com/latest/jquery-1.3.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://jqueryui.com/latest/ui/ui.core.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://jqueryui.com/latest/ui/ui.draggable.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(function() {

$(".container").draggable();

});


</script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <div id="draggable-1"></div>
  <div id="draggable-3"></div>
  <div id="draggable-4"></div>
  <div id="draggable-5"></div>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```