# Drag div by handle that is not nested

Tags: jquery, draggable

In the [JQueryUI draggable demo](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/#handle), I can see you can attach a handle to a DIV but if the handle is not nested within the parent DIV that is draggable, it doesn't work e.g.

```
<script src="jquery-1.5.2.js"></script>
  <script src="js/jquery-ui-1.8.11.custom.min.js"></script>

  <style>    
    #hBlack
    {
        width:55px;
        height:55px;
        background-color: black;
        top:0px;
    }

    #hGreen
    {
        width:25px;
        height:25px;
        background-color: green;


    }
  </style>
  <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
      $("#hBlack").draggable({handle:"#hGreen"});
      });
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="hBlack">
</div>
<div id="hGreen"></div>
```

The above doesn't make #hGreen the handle - but the following does:

```
<div id="hBlack">
  <div id="hGreen"></div>
</div>
```

Essentially, I am trying to make one DIV move when another moves - I guess you can do it with the [new Position utility](http://jqueryui.com/demos/position/) but for a newbie like me I find it poorly documented

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One possible solution could be to have the handle inside, but use css to position it outside.

Javascript:

```
$("#draggable").draggable({handle:"#handle"});
```

HTML:

```
 <div id="draggable">draggable
<div id="handle">handle</div>
 </div>
```

CSS:

```
#draggable{
display: block; 
height: 300px; 
width: 600px; 
background-color: gray;
}
#handle{
display: block; 
height: 50px; 
width: 600px; 
background-color: green;
position: relative;
top: -30px;
}
```

Otherwise, you might have to do something similar to a multiselect draggable.
[How do I drag multiple elements at once with JavaScript or jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5677993/how-do-i-drag-multiple-elements-with-javascript-or-jquery/5679450#5679450)

Comment: yup - makes sense - thanks - you may want to change the ID of the inner div to "handle" since your CSS has that

Comment: Thanks, those last minute changes get me a lot.