# moveing all draggable items together using jqueryui

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have 9 DIVs that i apply draggable to all of them. now i want to make them all move in the same pattern when one of them is dragged (as if i'm dragging all of them)

```
    $(".draggable").draggable({
    drag: function(event,ui){

    //i don't know what to write here, as i don't know what event and ui are.
// an .each will solve the problem if i get to know what these 2 arguments are

    }

    });
```

Comment: can you put all the divs under the same container?

Comment: they are under the same container but, the container must not move. i'm creating a sort map. that one of these DIVs will be visible and others will load data when they come into view.

Comment: yep. this is exactly what i want. thanks a lot. if you write it as an answer, i can choose it as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to drag multi divs but not all the container you can have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5677993/how-do-i-drag-multiple-elements-with-javascript-or-jquery).