# jQuery drag'n'drop multiple elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, drag-and-drop

I'm currently developing a web file browser using jquery and php.
One of my sub-tasks is to be able to select a couple of files/folders and drop them into another folder.

From my research I see that jquery ui has draggable and droppable which do the work at 80%.
What should be done to be able to select a couple of elements and drop them? 
Can it be done with the existing draggable/droppable plugins from jquery ui? 
If not can you recommend any plugins for jquery that can do the work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about http://www.myphpetc.com/2009/11/jquery-ui-multiple-draggable-plugin.html

Comment: In the comments there are links to droppable and sortable examples - http://www.myphpetc.com/2009/12/jquery-ui-sortable-drag-multiple-to.html and http://www.myphpetc.com/2009/12/accessing-draggable-elements-from.html

Answer (score 2):

This is by far the simplest solution that I've found to a multi-item drag and drop. It's by [brianpeiris](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22417/brianpeiris). He created a demo of it [here](http://jsbin.com/awagi) in answer to the stackoverflow question [grouping draggable objects with jquery-ui draggable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/793559/grouping-draggable-objects-with-jquery-ui-draggable). I just wish that I'd found it before I found all the other solutions.