# Ordering list with jQuery drag and drop

Tags: jquery, drag-and-drop

I need a jQuery to order a list like this:

http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/

But I need moving multiple items at once with the <kbd>CTRL</kbd> key example.

Do you know this script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to take a look at http://www.myphpetc.com/2009/11/jquery-ui-multiple-draggable-plugin.html

as seen in [jQuery drag'n'drop multiple elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8794178/jquery-dragndrop-multiple-elements)