# binding several jquery ui elements to each other

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is is possible to set up a group of multiple jquery ui elements to all respond to interactions with any one in the group?

**edit:**
For example, I've got several version of very similar images, which I've group into different pages with jquery.tabs(). The images are all manipulatable with various jquery ui things (dragable, resizable etc.). All of my tabs should look identical, except for the path to the images. So when I drag or resize an image in one tab, I'd like the corresponding image in a the other tabs to do the same.

Comment: Find this answer. It might be helpful. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/793559/grouping-draggable-objects-with-jquery-ui-draggable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do can be accomplished by using the events that the UI objects provide such as `drag` for `draggable()`:

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/elclanrs/WcNNb/2/

```
$('#drag1').draggable();
$('#drag2').draggable({
    drag: function(){
        $('#drag1').offset({
            top: $(this).offset().top,
            left: $(this).offset().left - $('#drag1').width() - 20
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

use for example:  `$('#element1').add($('#element2).draggable();`

but if you want to drag element1 when element2 is dragged :
since  during drag the element gets a class of ui-draggable-dragging use :

```
if($('#element1')).hasClass('ui-draggable-dragging')){
  //drag #element2
}
```

Comment: How about putting all grouped elements in a div and make the div draggable?

Comment: @jed i used add just to demonstrate if OP had two collection of elements like col1.add(col2)

Comment: I'm using jquery.tabs() for different versions of very similar data. I'm trying to make it so that a change in one tab will propagate and everything will look the same when switching into the other tabs... should I have included that in the question?

Comment: In that case, I would just use the `stop` callback to get the dragged object's new position and move the related elements on the other tabs to those coordinates (by specifying `top` and `left` or whatever).

Answer (score 1):

Let's make the assumption that similar elements have a common classname, eg `class="elementType_n".

Then you can select all similar elements and act on them as one or in sequence, as follows:

javascript:

```
$selection_n = $(".elementType_n");
$selection_n.on('eventType', function(){
    //Here, depending on the action, either
    //* act on $selection_n all together, eg. $selection_n.methodA(...)..methodB(...);
    // or
    //* act on $(this) with eg. $(this).methodA(...)..methodB(...); then use $(this)'s resulting properties to act on the rest of the selection, eg. $selection_n.not($(this).methodA(...)..methodB(...);
});
```

For draggables, there's no point dragging hidden elements in sympathy with the visible, dragged element. Who's going to see them move? Instead, establish a *drag.oncomplete* handler to set the invisibles' offsets to match the dragged element's offsets. End result - identical. Efficiency - greater. (Droppable is another matter).

Comment: Just added way ahead re. draggables.