# How to select multiple <li> drag and drop using jquery

Tags: jquery, drag-and-drop

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [jQuery Sortable - Select and Drag Multiple List Items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3774755/jquery-sortable-select-and-drag-multiple-list-items)

I need to drag and drop multiple `<li>` . Currently i can drag and drop single `<li>` . But i'm unable to select multiple `<li>` and drop

```
<ul id="draggable">
    <li class="lclass">1</li>
    <li class="lclass">2</li>
    <li class="lclass">3</li>
    <li class="lclass">4</li>
    <li class="lclass">5</li>
</ul>

<div class="droppable" >
    <p>Drop here</p>
</div>
```

JQUERY

```
   $(function() {
         $( ".lclass" ).draggable({ revert: true,scroll: false  });
         $( ".droppable" ).droppable({ drop: function( event, ui ) {}  });
    });
```

Please help me out.

Comment: This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/793559/grouping-draggable-objects-with-jquery-ui-draggable

Answer (score 0):

You can use [jQuery UI multiple draggable plugin](http://www.myphpetc.com/2009/01/jquery-multiple-draggable-elements.html) to do this.

Answer (score 0):

This bellow link may helps you

https://github.com/someshwara/MultiDraggable