# Multirow drag and drop in table (HTML / Javascript)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

Are there any jQuery plugins (or other Javascript libraries) that allow dragging and dropping (sorting) of multiple rows at the same time in a table?

I've found lots that support moving a single row at a time (e.g. http://isocra.com/2008/02/table-drag-and-drop-jquery-plugin/) but can't seem to find anything that will allow you to move more than one row at the same time.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279419/drag-and-drop-multiple-rows-from-one-table-to-another-table

Comment: Yep, I can always roll my own - just wondering if someone's done it already.