# How to drag and drop elements between two container

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-sortable

I have got two tables by name **Table 1** and **Table2** and  each table consists of two rows.

I could able to drag and drop elements within the same table

Could you please tell me If is it possible to drag and drop Table rows from Table 1 to Table 2 and vice versa (Moving rows within  different tables )

This is my HTML for the two tables

```
<h2>Table 1:</h2>
        <div id="table1" >
            <table>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Table 1 First Row</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Table 1 Second Row</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
 <hr/>
    <h2>Table 2:</h2>
   <div id="table2">
            <table>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Table 2 First Row</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Table 2 Second Row</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
```

and my js code

```
$("tbody").sortable({

});
```

This is my fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/wdy1ty89/7/

Comment: what did you  tried so far?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Drag and drop multiple rows from one table to another table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279419/drag-and-drop-multiple-rows-from-one-table-to-another-table)

Comment: @UnKnown check it: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39468056/1076753

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From **[jQuery UI](https://jqueryui.com/sortable/#connect-lists)**:

```
$("tbody").sortable({connectWith:"tbody"});
```

You should apply a min-width and height where the user can drag the element:

```
table{
  padding:5px 0; // To have a min height of 10px
  min-width:100px;
}
```

Check **[this Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wL4pkp9m/)**

Comment: Thanks a lot , but why the functionality is  not working once i move all the elements from table 1 Or Table 2 https://jsfiddle.net/wdy1ty89/8/

Comment: because you lost your tbody height after you move all your **tr**

Comment: no problem , i have seen this fiddle too http://jsfiddle.net/terryyounghk/Bs2jV/ but its of same table

Comment: Thanks a lot , i was actually struggling to do this